# Show that there exists $α \in F$ such that $S =\alpha T$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a (possibly infinite-dimensional) vector space over a field $F$. Let
$S : V \to F$ and let $T : V \to F$ be linear transformations. Assume that $N(S) \supseteq N(T)$. Show
that there exists $\alpha \in F$ such that $S = \alpha T$.

Need help I dont even know where to begin.
Thanks

Comment: What does $N(S)$ mean?

Comment: @user3491648 Null space of S. It seems that this question is exercise #6 from [here](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~heilman/teach/lalgset3.pdf), which seems to have a [corresponding set of notes](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~heilman/teach/lalgfull.pdf).

Comment: N(S) means null space of S

Answer (score 1):

In the following, $I(T)$ is the image of $T$.

The dimensions of $I(T)$ and $I(S)$ are either $0$ or $1$.

If $\dim I(T) = 0$ then $S = T = 0$ so $\alpha =$ anything.

If $\dim I(S) = 0$ then $S = 0$ so $\alpha = 0$ suffices.

This leaves $\dim I(T) = \dim I(S) = 1$. Let $v$ be such that $T(v) \not= 0$. Notice that $S(v) \not= 0$ because otherwise we would have $v \in N(S)$ but not $v \in N(T)$ which is impossible. So in that case $\alpha = \frac{S(v)}{T(v)}$.